# CSS Select :placeholder within an Id

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors, searchbar

I am styling the search bar on a Wordpress site and I need to modify the placeholder text for that bar only. I do not have access to the HTML.

Here's the code I have so far:

`#searchform-5aea17efae9386\.31889305 {
    border-radius:25px;
}`

I need the Placeholder text to be `color:#d2d4d3` - everything I've tried has changed the color of every instance of placeholder text instead of targeting the specific search bar.

Here is the HTML

`<input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" id="searchform-5aea17efae9386.31889305" placeholder="Search this website …">`

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `::placeholder` puesdo selector like pointed out in the comments. To target just that input just use a selector in front of the `::placeholder` style to target just that input.

You could use a selector that targets inputs whose `id` starts with (`^=`) "searchform", or just use that id if those numbers don't change.

`input[id^="searchform"]`

```css
input[id^="searchform"]::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
  color: red;
}
input[id^="searchform"]::-moz-placeholder { 
  color: red;
}
input[id^="searchform"]:-ms-input-placeholder { 
  color: red;
}
input[id^="searchform"]:-moz-placeholder { 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" id="searchform-5aea17efae9386.31889305" placeholder="Search this website …">

<br /><br />

<input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search this website …">
```